# Direct connection queries with groovy and dynamoDB

Tags: jdbc, groovy, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

im working with Quantrix, a java based modeling software.

I want to query from a NoSQL Database, DynamoDB to be precise. In Quantrix i can create a direct connection with a JDBC Driver.

I wonder wheather its possible to query directly with the script language of Quantrix (Groovy) from DynamoDB?

So is it possible to build a direct connection to DynamoDB with Groovy?

All the Best
Hector

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/community/#java

Comment: The AWS SDK for Java (v1 or v2) are both usable from groovy.  They're not SQL, and they're not JDBC, butyou can definitely access DynamoDb from groovy.  (the whole notion of a "connection" in the sense of persistent sql driver connections, doesn't really apply to DynamoDb since you access it (indirectly) through an HTTP API.